# How to check if a back button event has been called?

Tags: jquery, browser-history, hashtag

I am trying to make a site fully ajax supportive however I am having a hard time figuring out how to support history. I am using http://balupton.github.com/jquery-history/demo/ as my hash change library with jquery as such:

```
$(document).on('click','a',function(){
    var url = $(this).attr('href');
    $.ajax({
        // AJAX Call and populate
    });
    $.History.go(url);
    return false;
});
$('input[type="submit"]').livequery('click',function(event){
    $(this).closest("form").ajaxForm(get_pages_load_options);
    var url = $(this).closest("form").attr('action');
    $.History.go(url);
});
$('.get_pages').livequery('change',function(){
    $(this).closest("form").ajaxForm(get_pages_load_options);
    var url = $(this).closest("form").attr('action');
    $.History.go(url);
});
```

I am also using the following javascript for bookmarking:

```
function hash_process() {
    url = window.location.hash.replace('#', '');
    $.ajax({
        //AJAX Call and Populate
    });
}
if (window.location.hash) {
    hash_process();
}
```

However with the above two snippets I am finding that the back button does not work, especially with the submitted forms. If I add the following code it just gives me the default pages that do not have any submitted information like I never submitted the form in the first place.

```
window.onhashchange = hash_process;
```

Is there a way that I can check if the back button was called? Any ideas would be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer to this conundrum. Since the second call was being caused after I submitted the forms I ended up just adding an addition variable into the mix as follows:

```
ignore_hash = false;
function hash_process() {
    if (ignore_hash == false) {
        url = window.location.hash.replace('#', '');
        $.ajax({
            // AJAX Call & Populate
        });
    } else {
        ignore_hash = false;
    }
}
```

In the functions that were initiated before the check I added that variable into the execution:

```
$(document).on('click','a',function(){
    var url = $(this).attr('href');
    $.ajax({
        // AJAX Call & Populate
    });
    $.History.go(url);
    ignore_hash = true;
    return false;
});
```